# React Redux : TypeError: store.getState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm started to learn react and Redux, and I'm trying to apply it.
I have this error : TypeError: store.getState is not a function :

Thank you for your support and help.

App.JS

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <CustomButtonComponent/>
            <MissionDescriptionHomepageComponent/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

INDEX.JS

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
                <App/>
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

One componenet

```
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";

function MissionDescriptionHomepageComponent(props) {

    const {title, description} = useSelector(state => ({
        ...state.homePageDescriptionReducer,
    }))

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <p>{description}</p>

        </div>
    );
}


export default MissionDescriptionHomepageComponent;
```

the reducer

```
homePageDescriptionReducer

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    sections: [
        {
            title: 'Le titre du bloc',
            description: 'La description de la mission'
        }
    ]
}

const homePageDescriptionReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default homePageDescriptionReducer;
```

Where I'm going to combine my reducers, the root reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    homePageDescriptionReducer,
})

export default rootReducer;
```

the storeJS

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';

import rootReducer from './root-reducer'

 const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default {store};
```

If you have any suggestion or advice about this skeleton of code, don't hesitate to tell me to.

Thank you for your support and help.

Comment: Also, quick tip: `useSelector(state => ({ ...state.homePageDescriptionReducer }))` this creates a new object each time the selector is called, and re-renders even if it didn't change. instead just use the object directly: `useSelector(state => state.homePageDescriptionReducer)`

Comment: Also, it looks like the `homePageDescriptionReducer` has a `sections` property, not the `title` and `description` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exporting the store:

```
export default {store};
```

You need to import it:

```
import {store} from './redux/store';
```

Comment: Sorry for disturbing more, I didn't understand. In the store.js I did an export, and in the index.js I did the import {store}. I need to remove the export default {store} ?

Comment: Don't remove the export default {store}, Other thing you can do in store.js is export default store without {}, and then in index.js: import store from "..

Comment: Also this line will fail const {title, description} = useSelector(state => ({
        ...state.homePageDescriptionReducer,
    })), change it to:     const {title, description} = useSelector(state => 
        state.homePageDescriptionReducer.sections
    )

Comment: hello, thanks, yes I only had to export default store without {}. And thank you for the advice